# after subtoals need to insert line below them and need to add a top border in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim iRange As Range
Dim iCells As Range

Set iRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each iCells In iRange
    'If Not IsEmpty(iCells) Then
    If iCells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas) = True Then
        iCells.BorderAround _
            LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
            Weight:=xlThin
    End If
Next iCells
```

[See Excel Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8djSo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try using the next code. No iteration needed:

```
Sub BordrsOnSubtotals()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, rngForm As Range
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no formulas in the sheet...
    Set rngForm = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Not rngForm Is Nothing Then
       rngForm.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
       Intersect(rngForm.EntireRow, sh.UsedRange.EntireColumn).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = 3
   End If
   'Excel inserts lines for the range Areas and the last two are in the same area and needs correction:
   sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1).EntireRow.Delete
   Intersect(sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).EntireRow, _
                  sh.UsedRange.EntireColumn).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jaiprakash Didn't the above code solve your problem?

Comment: Hi but what about the balnk row below the subtotal as the above code added top border but do not worked for blank row insertion

Comment: @Jaiprakash I'm afraid I cannot get you... What "blank row insertion"? It should add a `Top` border to the cells keeping a formula, as your code tried to do...

Comment: Yes you got it right but i need a blank row after each  row as well and the border needs in complete row of that special cell

Comment: @Jaiprakash I do not think that any blank row will bother the code logic. About the entire row, you did not say anything... I only tried deducing what you want from your code (not working as you need), which places a border around the cell... I can adapt it to place the line above all the line with formulas. But do you wont it for all the row, or only for the filled columns?

Comment: 1. You are not understanding my need I have written another code for inserting a blank code after special cell that is also not working below is the code that i found in a forum : 
'''For Each oneCell In Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
   ''' With oneCell
    '''    If .Formula Like "=SUBTOTAL*" And 1 < .Row Then
     '''        oneCell.Offset(-1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
     '''   End If
    '''End With
'''Next oneCell

Comment: @Jaiprakash Where did you write the code you are mentioning? Is it somewhere in your question and I missed it? Anyhow, I missed the part mentioning the necessity of a row insertion. I will adapt the above code to do it, too.

Comment: @Jaiprakash Please, try the updated code and send some feedback

Comment: Kindly ,How does your code distinguish between `SubTotoal` and other fourmals? @FaneDuru

Comment: @Waleed It does not! It is answered based on a question title and a non working piece of code. Since he tried that code, I assumed that no other formulas are in the sheet. Otherwise, he should mention about them. The code can extract formulas from the column keeping subtotals. If in that column are other formulas, he certainly should specify that. In such a case the range must be checked against a specific string.